# Is AWS S3 corrupting some unicode characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, unicode

I'm trying to upload a text file that has the following line:

```
var ε = 1e-6, ε2 = ε * ε, π = Math.PI, τ = 2 * π, τε = τ - ε, halfπ = π / 2, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

When I point my web browser at the file in the bucket, it displays like this:

```
  var Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2 = Îµ * Îµ, Ï€ = Math.PI, Ï„ = 2 * Ï€, Ï„Îµ = Ï„ - Îµ, halfÏ€ = Ï€ / 2, d3_radians = Ï€ / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / Ï€;
```

When I download the file using wget and open it up, it looks fine.

Why isn't the browser interpreting the unicode correctly? Do I need to adjust the content-type or something?

Comment: You need to read it as UTF8.

Comment: When you use the browser to look at it there's no HTML involved, right? Look at https://www.w3.org/International/articles/http-charset/index#charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As SLaks and Mark Ransom suggested, setting the content-type header to include charset=utf-8 fixed the issue.